# Left-aligned axis labels when using cowplot to switch x axis to top

Tags: r, ggplot2, cowplot

I'm trying to make a correlation heatmap where the x axis is moved to the top using `cowplot::switch_axis_position`. I have axis labels of varying length and I want the labels to be left-aligned (or rather bottom-aligned, because they are rotated 90 degrees). Although I manage to align the labels, they are moved up far above the plot.

```
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)
library(cowplot)

# some toy data
set.seed(1)
mydata <- mtcars[, c(1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)]

# to show difference in justification better, make names of unequal length 
names(mydata) = paste0(sample(c("mtcars_", ""), 6, replace = TRUE), names(mydata))
cormat <- round(cor(mydata), 2)

melted_cormat <- melt(cormat)
head(melted_cormat)
```

First a plot where the x axis is moved to the top, and the labels are centered vertically:

```
plot <- ggplot(data = melted_cormat, aes(x=Var1, y=Var2, fill=value)) + 
        geom_tile() +
        theme_bw(base_size=20) + xlab("") + ylab("") +
        theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust = 0.5))
ggdraw(switch_axis_position(plot, 'x'))
```

[image: link]

Then I use the same code as above but with `hjust = 0` instead to left-align the x axis text. It indeed aligns the text, but the text is moved weirdly far from graph so variable names are cut off: [image: link]

Any ideas of how to fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Please note: this bug is no longer present in the latest version of `cowplot` on CRAN.

#### Old answer:

It seems this is a bug for the special case of `angle = 90`. We can circumvent this by adding an arbitrarily small value to `angle`.

```
plot <- ggplot(data = melted_cormat, aes(x=Var1, y=Var2, fill=value)) + 
  geom_tile() + theme_bw(base_size=20) + xlab("") + ylab("")+
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90 + 1e-09, hjust = 0, vjust=1)) +
  coord_equal(expand = 0)
ggdraw(switch_axis_position(plot, 'x'))
```

[image]

Comment: Nice. I had just finished my answer with padded_out column names and changing the font family to "mono".... but this is way better.

Comment: Haha, not sure why this works though. I'm filing a github issue.

Comment: You should file it as a bug, you can reference this post I think.

Comment: thanks. that's odd. Is there a way to also get the labels centered on the tick mark? probably not?

Comment: You can play with `vjust` values slightly below 1 to get them closer, but it seems you'll have to trade off centering and distance from the axis. Quite unpredictable behavior indeed!